# What's wrong with string "jo" when parsing json?

Tags: java, android, json

I have json string:

```
String jsonString = "{\"first\":{\"1\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"jo\"}]}}";

JSONObject users = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray sub = users.getJSONArray("first");
```

But in `JSONArray` sub I have error:

> org.json.JSONException
>   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch

But if I have:

```
String jsonString = "{\"first\":{\"1\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"other\"}]}}";

JSONObject users = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray sub = users.getJSONArray("first");
```

It doesn't give any error.

Why with string `"jo"` I have an error?

Comment: Are you sure ??? There isn't any problem here

Comment: Yes, I am testing this in Android.

Comment: Unless you have two single quotes ('') in first syntax , there is no issue here. Validate your json using jsonlint or codebeautify.

Comment: I don't see you using `jsonString` while constructing JSONObject or parsing JSONArray.

Comment: **first** is not JSONArray type object

Comment: Try this : `String jsonString = "{\"first\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"jo\"}]}";`

Comment: `{\"1\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"other\"}]}` is not a JSONArray, but JSONObject. Both `jsonString` examples fail with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**first** is not JSONArray,it is JSONObject.so cast it to JSONObject and then get **1** from it.You will get the JSONArray.

Below is the working example for both json string:

```
      String jsonString = "{\"first\":{\"1\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"jo\"}]}}";
    //String jsonString = "{\"first\":{\"1\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"other\"}]}}";

    JSONObject users;
    try {
        users = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        users=users.getJSONObject("first");
        JSONArray sub = users.getJSONArray("1");
        System.out.println(sub.get(0));
    } catch (JSONException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

output:

{"name":"jo","id":1}

Comment: Why you have a `main(String[] args)` function here? It's **Android**

Comment: I have given an working example.its not platform specific

Comment: @Arash Hatami-where it is written that it is android related problem?

Comment: @vikastandon The `android` tag of the question. Also [comment by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51004241/whats-wrong-with-string-jo-when-parsing-json#comment89002053_51004241).

Answer (score 0):

Your json strings are wrong. There isn't any `JsonArray`

Change string like this :

```
String jsonString = "{\"first\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"name1\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"name2\"}]}";

JSONObject users = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray sub = users.getJSONArray("first");
for (int i = 0; i < sub.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject user = sub.getJSONObject(i);

    String userID = user.gatInt("id");
    String userName = user.gatString("name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are getting such error due to string change to "jo" because that does't seems problem to me. 
I have done some modifications in your code and it works fine :

```
String jsonString = "{\"first\":{\"1\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"jo\"}]}}";

JSONObject users = JSON.parse(jsonString); 
JSONArray sub = users.first;
```